# Proving that $\lim_{x {\to} \infty}f(x)=\infty $

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

Given $\ f(x)$ that is differential in $\ (x_0,\infty), f'(x)\ge a,$ for every $\ x> x_0$ and $\ a>0$, trying to show that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty$.

So far I've tried using Mean Value Theorem on $\ [b,b+1],$ so that $\ b>x_0$. From there I assumed in order to contradict, that $\ f(x)$ converges to a finite $\ L$. So 
$$ \lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=  \lim_{x\to\infty} f(b+1)-f(b)= L -L=0$$
This is against that (*)$\ f'(x) > 0$ so $\ f(x)$ does not converge to a finite value. Finally $\ f(x)$ is strictly increasing ($\ f'(x)\ge a>0$) so it tends to infinity. 
$$$$
I think that * might be faulty, if the limit of a derivative is zero it doesn't mean that the actual derivative is affected so. Maybe there is a different direction to approach this. Any input? Maybe this should be solved in a different way?

Comment: Your reasoning is correct but perhaps you have a typo and you need slightly more justification. Since $$f(x + 1) - f(x) = f'(c_{x})\tag{1}$$ for $x < c_{x} < x + 1$, it follows that $f(x)$ can't tends to a finite limit $L$ because if it were so, LHS of $(1)$ would tend to $0$ and RHS would remain always greater than (or equal to) $a$. And since $f$ is strictly increasing the only option left for $f$ is diverge to $\infty$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $x> x_0,$ the MVT gives

$$f(x) - f(x_0) = f'(c_x)(x-x_0) \ge a(x-x_0).$$

The result follows quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Your method is wrong because not having limit of $\infty$ does not at all imply that there is a finite limit! Instead you must expand the definition of infinite limit and directly prove that. It should not be hard.